Enclosing filename in quotes affects batch input
Let's say I have a batch file C:\MyFile.bat as follows:
echo This is my batch file
pause

I invoke it like this, because I need a new console window to open:
start /wait C:\MyFile.bat

I get the expected result... a new console window opens, displays the echo and waits on the pause.
However, if I instead name the batch file C:\My File.bat (space in the file's name), I must now enclose the filename in doublequotes, as follows:
start /wait "C:\My File.bat"

However doing so does not result as expected. A new console window is opened, but the specified batch file does not execute.

What's going on?
How can I achieve my desired result when the target file location requires doublequoting?


The first thing I'd ask is why are you using start? What is wrong with just "C:\My File.bat", or as you seem to be wanting to do something afterwards, (hence /wait), then Call "C:\My File.bat".

@Compo In the context of use, I need a new console window to open; call won't do that, but start will.

The answer you received and have accepted, has been posted on this site, with the [[tag:batch-file]] tag, many hundreds of times, and is essentially just an extended explanation of the built in help for the start command. For that reason, it should have been easily found by using the search box at the top of the page, and should not have needed to be asked again.

Additionally, there is absolutely no reason for me not to have mentioned other options for you to explore, in order for you to perform the same task without the need to use the command you were reporting an issue with using. Is there any particular reason that you are unwilling to explore those options and report back what happens so that future readers could be informed on whether those alternatives could be employed by them instead?

start considers the first set of quotes that it finds to be the title of the new window.
To get around this, add a throwaway set of quotes to the command:
start "" /wait "C:\My File.bat"


@Zenilogix It would be best in your case giving the console window a meaningful title. You should know for which task the batch file is executed and what could be a meaningful window title. "" as window title is usually used for Windows GUI applications on which no console window is opened at all. The command line should be better: start "meaningful title" /wait %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C "C:\My File.bat" It is advisable to explicitly specify cmd.exe with full path and with option /D for processing the batch file. The option /D is not used on using just the batch file name.
